# Make Checkbox look like CheckboxPreference

Tags: android, android-checkbox, preferencefragment

I want to be able to use the CheckboxPreference outside of PreferenceFragment.

How do I make my checkbox look like a CheckboxPreferece?

Majorly I want the checkbox to be on the right. I tried setting style to `@style/Preference.Checkbox`. But this didn't work.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/map_shown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_extra_small"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{ (switch, checked) -> event.setMapShown(checked) }"
    style="@style/Preference.CheckBoxPreference"
    android:text="@string/show_map" />
```

I need this to look like:

```
<android.support.v7.preference.CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="map_shown"
    android:title="Show Map"
    android:summaryOff="Map is shown"
    android:summaryOn="Map is not shown"
    android:defaultValue="false"/>
```

Comment: share your code.

Comment: @HemantParmar I think the code should be irrelevant, but I have shared the code

Comment: well you have to extend Checkbox for set custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For align checkbox right side to the `textview`, then try to use [CheckedTextview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView).

```
<CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="CheckedTextView" />
```

[image]

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Your code only changes the background. I don't want to change the background. I only want my checkbox to look like a PreferenceCheckbox (which has checkbox on the right), i.e. the one found in settings. Also, is there no way without extending the checkbox (like using styles)?

Comment: which has checkbox on the right?? can you more explain it.

Comment: You must have seen the Settings Activity (PreferenceFragment or PreferenceActivity) in apps. The PreferenceCheckbox have the checkbox on the right side and the text on the left side. Whereas, the normal Checkbox widget has its checkbox on the left and text on the right.

Comment: ohk means you want checkbox on right side and text on left side??

Comment: Yes, along with a summary, and if possible, in a clean way without having to extend the base class.

Comment: ok, than you have to use [CheckedTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView), for example have look [this](http://www.wingnity.com/blog/use-checkedtextview-android/)

Comment: CheckedTextView is to be used for lists. It doesn't react to user clicks. And I am also not able to see the checkbox.